# Hiding list view items in listview wpf C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following `ListView` which contains the following XAML definition:

```
<ListView Height="307" Width="991" Name="OrderListView" ItemsSource="{ Binding Orders }">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isVisible}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="A header" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StoreNumber}"></GridViewColumn>
                    ...
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And the model which is linked to data context:

```
public sealed class DDModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
   {
            get;
            set;
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and Order has a boolean property `isVisible` (see the trigger from style)

I create an event for text box at keyup:

```
private void OrderSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _backup = this.DataContext as DDModel;

    string keyword = this.OrderSearch.Text;

    var query = _backup.Orders.ToList();

    // make them all visible
    query.ForEach(p => p.isVisible = true);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
    {
        //then hide the items which doesn't match with keyword
        query.Where(p => !p.OrderNumber.ToString().StartsWith(keyword)).ToList().ForEach(p => p.isVisible = false);
    }
}
```

The ListView is not refreshed, the trigger doesn't work and some items are not hidden.

But `_backup` contains few items which `isVisible` is set to false;

Where is my mistake ?

PS: The `Orders` is not null or empty, is loaded from database when window is initialised. The listview also is not empty, contains few records (rows).

Comment: Did you consider simply putting a filter on the underlying collection view?  Based upon what you wrote, you could eliminate the triggers and handle the filtering in your code behind.

Comment: Can you show me clear documentation for listview.datacontext only ? I found mostly for datagrid

Comment: It is independent of data context; in your case you would get the collection view source of _backup.Orders and cast it into ListCollectionView and then set the filter on it.  Very straight forward.  You can even use an anonymous delegate.  I wrote the wiki tag over here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/listcollectionview/info if it's of any use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or a base class which implements that interface) for your class `Order`. Setup your properties correctly by using the `OnPropertyChanged` function provided by the interface. That is required since your ObservableCollection `Orders` does not get notified when an **instance** of an item in the list changes.

This might look as follows:

```
class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Boilerplate code..

    private bool _Visible ;

    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _Visible; }
        set
        {
            if (_Visible == value) return;
            _Visible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => _Visible);
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you should implement the same functionality for your ObservableCollection `Orders`.

Your triggerevent should be fired as well when the `Visible` property changes.

Comment: What is definition of `OnPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956165/wpf-onpropertychanged-for-a-property-within-a-collection